# Recognise the true indexPath of a long tapped UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to detect a long tapped table view cell within collection view.

I have my main view controller (MainVC class) which contains a CollectionView (CollectionViewController class). The collection view has a label and a TableView (TableViewController class) for each cell. 
The collection view delegate methods are implemented inside MainVC and the tableView delegate methods are implemented inside CollectionViewController class.

I'm trying to detect the tableViewCell indexPath (In order to get it's content) when long tapped.

The code performing the detection (Inside CollectionViewController):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longTapped(longPressGestureRecognizer:)))
        longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
    }

func longTapped(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self)

        if let indexPath = self.eventsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            print(indexPath.row) //print the current *displayed* cell index
        }
    }
}
```

The system recognise the long tap, **but I ran into a problem**. This code:

```
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchedPoint)
```

which suppose to recognise the tapped cell indexPath, seems to find the tapped cell index which **currently displayed**. I mean that if there are 20 cells above which are not currently displayed by the device, the `indexPathForRow` will ignore them, and count the displayed cells only. 
So for example, If I have 30 rows on a table view and the user is currently looking at the cell in the 23rd row, the system will consider the cell to be (for example) in the 4th row, because it's the 4th cell which currently displayed.

I have no idea if there's a connection to the fact that this tableView is lies within a collection view, but I hope this extra info will help you help me (:

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longPressGestureRecognized))
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
 }

@objc func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let longPress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
        if longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
            let locationInTableView = longPress.location(in: tableView)
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: locationInTableView)
            print(indexPath?.row ?? "-0")
        }
}
```

Comment: First, I love you. Second, the problem was indeed in this line: let locationInTableView = longPress.location(in: tableView), I checked the location in self instead in tableView. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score -1):

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` i think will be in your help. Check what is it, and don't forget delegate `tableView` before use it

Comment: I'm trying to detect a long tap not a regular one. So didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not help me. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You have to add your long tap recognizer to a custom cell so. That works for sure